# nginx specific url to purge

Tags: nginx, cache

I am looking for a way to purge nginx cache using by adding a specific annotation on url.

Let's say I have this url (item) cached with nginx:

```
http://mywebsite/render/render5.php?frame=1&image=nature-1920.jpg
```

If I want to purge it, I would have to add:

```
http://mywebsite/render/render5.php?frame=1&image=nature-1920.jpg&purge=1
```

Is that possible to purge an URL if we add at the end of this URL `&purge=1`?

All tutorials I find use the `curl -X` command to purge a specific item, for example:

```
curl -X PURGE http://mywebsite/render/render5.php?frame=1&image=nature-1920.jpg
```

https://scene-si.org/2016/11/02/purging-cached-items-from-nginx-with-lua/

And I want to be able to purge an nginx cached item (url) without having to use `curl -X` command.

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying the solution provided in the link you included?

Comment: I don't know how to, if I have `&purge=1` in the url I must remove it to get the right URL to purge.

Answer (score 2):

The linked tutorial adds the purge feature using a Lua script, so it would be possible to modify it to use `&purge=1` instead of PURGE http method. *However*, it's not advisable for a production system.

A guiding principle of [HTTP/REST service design](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is that GET requests (ie what happens when you call `curl <url>`) are "safe", meaning they should basically be read-only without any side effects. One reason for this is that clients may call them in advance, e.g. a web browser is at liberty to call URLs shown on a page as soon as it loads, as a performance boost. This would purge the cache.